# Accessing global variable in your .ctp file?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm learning cakePHP at the moment. I'm trying to show the particular username that is currently logged in.

So what I've done is that:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $username = '';
    if($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
        $username = $this->Auth->user('username');
    }
    $this->globalUsername = $username;
}
```

I'm assuming that in any of the pages I should be able to access globalUsername as a variable?

Is that correct or is there  a better way of doing that?

Many thanks!

Comment: $this->set('globalUsername', $username); Read the docs for basics it will save your time too. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#View::set

Comment: Also , There is a session for auth set which can help you get data in view . $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username');

Answer (score 1):

You have to be doing this in the AppController, if you want it to be accessible by all pages on the site.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $globalUsername;   

    public function beforeFilter() {
      $username = ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) ? $this->Auth->user('username') : NULL;
      $this->globalUsername = $username;
    }
}
```

Also, I just converted it to the short-hand version of the IF statement. You can use the full-fledged version like you had initially as well. The important thing is to declare the public variable outside of your method.

Now, in any .ctp file, first check if the variable is not NULL. Then simply just echo out `$this->globalUsername;`

Comment: you are correct. This could be done in many ways, its upto you how you approach towards it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->set(compact('username'));
```

Try this so you can use $username in your views.

Answer (score 0):

Look through the blog tutorial and/or the docs:

```
$this->set('username', $username);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pull the information from the session in the default layout? No need to write it in the controller.

```
$username = AuthComponent::user('username');
```